# What is the gdbserver used when running linux kernel on qemu?

Tags: linux, gdb, kernel, qemu, gdbserver

I am new to kernel debugging using gdb. Few days back I read that we can turn on KGDB which is a gdb server running in the kernel . We can connect to this gdbserver on kernel using the gdb client on host machine used for development.

Today I came across a different solution where we run the kernel on a virtual environment on qemu. There we do not turn on the KGDB still we can connect to the qemu using gdb client. I think "gdbstub" acts as the gdbserver here and gdb client connects to QEMU and not the kernel. Is my understanding correct? This setup is somewhat similar to using a JTAG to control the cpu rather than the kernel. Is this correct?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that's right. QEMU includes a built-in gdbstub which allows you to connect a debugger to it to get "system-level" debugging somewhat analagous to a JTAG level debugger on real hardware. This means that you don't need any support in the guest code for debugging, and you can debug situations where the guest code is broken to the point where its built-in debug support might be non-functional; and of course it works for guest OSes which have no low-level debug support of their own. On the other hand, it means that the debug stub has no understanding of the guest OS and so it cannot present you with any information about guest OS internals like processes and it can't provide OS-aware debug actions like "debug this guest OS userspace process only".

Whether the guest Linux KGDB support or QEMU's gdbstub is more useful to you will depend on the particular situation and requirements you have.

Comment: +1 : This also explains why I could not see list of running processes in case of gdbstub on qemu but I could using kgdb.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to build your custom guest Linux kernel with debug info (symbols) available then run it in the guest, then when you use gdbstub in QEMU, you can load the symbols from the host gdb.